# How to modify a CSS display property from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the display CSS property of a `<div>` tag when the user changes the value of a `<select>`.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<select type="text" name="category" onblur="display_hidden_fields();">
    <option><!-- Content --></option>
    <option><!-- Content --></option>
</select>

<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    <label for="test">Label</font></label>
    <select type="text" name="test">
        <option value="1">Default</option>
        <option value="2">Value1</option>
        <option value="3">Value2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

(note that's a simplified version of my code. Actually, every `<label>` and `<select>` are in `<td>`. I think it doesn't matter)

Now, my JS code :

```
function display_hidden_fields()
{
    alert("JS Function");
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
}
```

Well. When I select a new `<option>` in the first `<select>` named "category", I get the alert "JS Function". So my `display_hidden_fields()` function is correctly executed.
But the second line of this function does... nothing ! My `<div>` named "hidden" is not displayed :(

It seems to me there is nothing wrong in my code. Moreover, I tried many variants.
 - Like specifying `style="display:block"` in the `<div>` properties, and changing it to "none" in the JS.
 - Or trying to use other properties like "inline", "inline-block", ...
 - Or using "visibility" instead of "display"
 - Or not specifying any property at all in the HTML.

Does anyone can help me ? :)

Thanks.

### [EDIT] Important observation

I think I found something interesting. It seems that a `<div>` with `display:none;` mixed with `<tr>` and `<td>` is completely nonfunctional. Here is my real code :

```
<tr>
    <div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
        <td class="depot_table_left">
            <label for="sexe">Sexe</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select type="text" name="sexe">
                <option value="1">Sexe</option>
                <option value="2">Joueur</option>
                <option value="3">Joueuse</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

The content of the `<div>` is still displayed. And I can try to change it in any way in JS, it doesn't work.
I also tried to remove the `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, and it works fine. But I need this table...

Comment: `onchange` instead of `onblur` and `("hidden")` instead of `["hidden"]`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using [] in my code, it was just a mistake during copying.
Concerning onchange, I don't see the point to use it. onblur is working since my JS function is correctly executed.

Comment: How on earth do you manage to change `()` into `[]` during copy/paste? I can't see anything else wrong with your code. Make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) test case.

Comment: Anyway, I just tried onchange, and there is no other change that the normal behaviour difference between onblur and onchange.

Comment: I didn't copy/paste my code, I re-typed it (cause there is many french words in my code. It would be more disturbing than usefull)

Comment: The better way would be to copy/paste your code into jsFiddle, change it so that all the French is gone, and make sure the problem still happens. If it does, edit your question with the link.

Comment: well do you have any javascript errors in the browser? Maybe put a 2nd alert after you change the display to see if it executes. My only guess here is you may have a type in the ID.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It should be
`document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";`
not
`document.getElementById["hidden"].style.display = "block";`

---

**EDIT due to author edit:**

Why are you using a `<div>` here? Just add an ID to the table element and add a hidden style to it. E.g. `<td id="hidden" style="display:none" class="depot_table_left">`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using [] in my code, it was just a mistake during copying.

Comment: In that case the code you posted works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: I didn't see your EDIT. I just found the same solution so I answered myelf :) Anyway, I validate your answer, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

As said in the EDIT of my answer, a `<div>` is misfunctioning in a `<table>`.
So I wrote this code instead :

```
<tr id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    <td class="depot_table_left">
        <label for="sexe">Sexe</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select type="text" name="sexe">
            <option value="1">Sexe</option>
            <option value="2">Joueur</option>
            <option value="3">Joueuse</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is working fine.

Thanks everybody ;)

Answer (score 1):

CSS properties should be set by `cssText` property or `setAttribute` method.

```
// Set multiple styles in a single statement
elt.style.cssText = "color: blue; border: 1px solid black"; 
// Or
elt.setAttribute("style", "color:red; border: 1px solid blue;");
```

Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the `style` property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the `style` attribute returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which is also read-only.